# SSRS : How to set SSRS stack chart X axis set range as <2500, 2500-4999

Tags: reporting-services, charts, stack

[How to set SSRS stack chart X axis set range as <2500, 2500-4999 ....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqHHL.png)

Comment: Please specify more details and e.g. add an example

Comment: group the data in your dataset query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SWITCH or multiple IIFs for the Category Group to group your data in a chart.

For the Group Expressions, you'd want something like

```
=SWTICH(Fields!Number.Value < 2500, "< 2,500", 
    Fields!Number.Value >= 2500 AND Fields!Number.Value <= 4999, "2500 - 4999",
    Fields!Number.Value >= 5000 AND Fields!Number.Value <= 7499, "5000 - 7499", 
    Fields!Number.Value >= 7500 AND Fields!Number.Value <= 9999, "7500 - 9999",
    Fields!Number.Value >= 10000, "10000+")
```

Or you could use nested IIFs:

```
=IIF(Fields!Number.Value < 2500, "< 2,500", 
 IIF(Fields!Number.Value >= 2500 AND Fields!Number.Value <= 4999, "2500 - 4999",
 IIF(Fields!Number.Value >= 5000 AND Fields!Number.Value <= 7499, "5000 - 7499",
 IIF(Fields!Number.Value >= 7500 AND Fields!Number.Value <= 9999, "7500 - 9999",
 IIF(Fields!Number.Value >= 10000, "10000+", "Unknown")))))
```